# Replace the default MessageBox

Tags: extjs4

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

When I use Ext.MessageBox.show({...}) it show the box like IMG2 default. I want to use the box like IMG1 and how could I replace it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
you should use loadMask for your extjs component.

// Basic mask:
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
myMask.show();
```